# Can we show offline ads when user is offline?

Tags: android

Can we show offline ads when user is offline? I have an app when users usually used offline.

Comment: Are you *able* to, or are you *allowed* to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can. It's your painting surface, you can put what you want on it, even ads that you've previously downloaded while online, or ones hard-coded in your app itself.

However, I'm assuming you wish to be *paid* for displaying these ads (such as with AdMob or Mobclix) and I'm not aware of any way to have "offline" ads feed into your ad account at whatever provider you've chosen.

And, as Eric intelligently points out in a comment, the ads are meant to be clicked upon. It's a little hard to convert those clicks into revenue if your device if off-line since you can't get through to the web site *behind* the ad :-)

Comment: +1 Agreed with this answer. I just had to comment to add that the ads can't link anywhere if you're offline.

Comment: @Eric, a very intelligent observation, and one I'm ashamed I didn't see myself :-)